# Unable to build .class file through Runtime class compilation

Tags: java, runtime.exec

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String sout;
        try
          {         
            if(e.getSource()==compile)
            {
            sout=input.getText();
            Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();                            
Process p=rt.exec("javac sout.java",null,new     File("C:/c/compile assign"));
            }
```

I am storing the class name in String sout(through TextField) then calling sout.java (i.e classname.java) but it was unable to build a class file.

```
            if(e.getSource()==run)
            {
InputStream is = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java input.getText()",null,new             File("C:/c/compile assign")).getInputStream();
            //BufferedInputStream b=new BufferedInputStream(is);
         BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));      
            output.setText(br.readLine()+"hello");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
        e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Commands to `exec` or better `ProcessBuilder` are better kept in a `String[]`.  Be sure to visit the Java World article linked from the [`exec` info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/runtime.exec/info).  Implement all the recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're keeping the classname in a string `sout` as supplied in the `input` textfield then your output compile command should be:

```
Process p=rt.exec("javac " + sout + ".java", null, new File("C:/c/compile assign"));
```

Also your run command should be:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java " + input.getText(), null, new File("C:/c/compile assign")).getInputStream();
```

You will probably want to add further validation before using the raw value (e.g. class exists) from this field before launching the `java` command.